# Link detection for HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed

Links to HTTPS URL's aren't automatically converted to be clickable, see this example on serverfault:

[Syntax highlight in bugzilla](https://serverfault.com/questions/33630/syntax-highlight-in-bugzilla)

Comment: will be deployed later

Comment: Some of the more complex Wikipedia links (eg, including underscores and parentheses) still aren't linked properly.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see if FTP works: ftp://ftp.somesite.com/web

So if all these cases could be detected that would be great.

Comment: I would say no to clickable emails, but yes to https, ftp, and perhaps any other major ones.